# Suitable replacement for a Logitech MXAir Mouse?

Tags: mice

I got the Logitech MXAir mouse back around 2007 when I decided to center my entertainment center around a Mac mini and I have loved it ever since. It's perfect for using my TV-connected computer from the couch. It has lasted me a solid decade and a half. The key features that I love are:

- move the cursor by waving the mouse in the air like a wii remote
- 8 programmable buttons.
- You can even program something to happen when you shake it (I have mine set to trigger Mission Control)
- and with 1 button set to the control key, I can use control-scroll to zoom the screen. This is essential, especially given my aging eyes.
- A touch surface for smooth scrolling with momentum

The problem is that the driver is no longer supported and it tends to crash. Basic functionality persists and I can launch the driver, and that restores full functionality. I put the driver in the dock since it no longer appears in system preferences.

But sometimes, lately, it won't even move the cursor for 10-20 seconds. I know it's connected because if I shake it, it triggers Mission Control. But I'm not sure this is due to the driver. I think the mouse's hardware itself is failing. So it seems time to replace it.

But after googling for an hour, I was shocked to discover that there appears to be no similar mouse on the market!? Given how much I love this mouse, I was astounded there's not a suitable modern day version of it to be found. I found some cheap clunky ones on aliexpress, but nothing as elegant, let alone as functional as the MXAir. Please, someone tell me there's something out there. And if not, does anyone know how to fix the problems I'm having with my MXAir?